# Ionic (browser/iOS) How do I check if user ALREADY has granted a permission?

Tags: ionic-framework, permissions, ionic4

I know this is easy to do with an Android device, because there is a Cordova plugin for that. How do I check if the browser user (or iOS user) has already granted a permission ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to invoke something native related to device, it can be not executed in the browser :

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's only talking about android permissions. Is there a way to check if my broswser already has acces to my location for example?

Comment: I think it should be implemented native https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation, because your target is a mobile application, not a web app, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp for borwer location